# regex to extract consecutive single-line comments when a specific string is contained within

Tags: java, regex

Consider an SQL file as follows that contains a number of single-line comments:

```
-- I'm a little teapot
<<< not a comment >>>
-- some random junk
-- random Mary had a
-- little lamb random
-- more random junk
<<< not a comment >>>
```

Using regex, I was looking to match the string `Mary.*?lamb` and extract all consecutive (above and below) single line comments.

The expected output would be:

```
-- some random junk
-- random Mary had a
-- little lamb random
-- more random junk
```

I was trying something along these lines but had no luck.

```
(--[\S\t\x20]*\n)*?(--[\S\t\x20]*?Mary.*?lamb[\S\t\x20]*?\n)(--[\S\t\x20]*\n)*
```

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by extract consecutive...  Can you show what is your expected output?

Comment: I've edited question to explain better hopefully. Essentially I want all comments surrounding the string I'm looking for.

Comment: Does it not match at all, or not match all four lines?  Shouldn't the first `*?` be greedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like that:

```
^((?:--(?:(?!Mary)[^\n])*[\r\n]{1,2})*)(--[^\n]+?Mary[\s\S]+?lamb[^\n]+[\r\n]{1,2})((?:--(?:(?!Mary)[^\n])*[\r\n]{1,2})*)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cA6qD4)

And since it's Java, you will probably have to add some backslashes before the ones in the regex above for it to work:

```
^((?:--(?:(?!Mary)[^\\n])*[\\r\\n]{1,2})*)(--[^\\n]+?Mary[\\s\\S]+?lamb[^\\n]+[\\r\\n]{1,2})((?:--(?:(?!Mary)[^\\n])*[\\r\\n]{1,2})*)
```

I'm using `[\\r\\n]{1,2}` because I can't be sure whether or not the file has only `\n`, or only `\r` or `\r\n`, so that it will work in all cases (though it can match two newlines in a row, but there's the `--` which makes it fine).

Comment: thanks that seems to work well. And cheers for the demo, it will help in trying to understand